# Unity poor performance after upgrading to 13.10

Tags: unity, drivers, upgrade

I upgraded recently from 13.04 to 13.10. I have Dell Inspiron 4GB RAM, Intel Core i3. Login takes a lot of time and all the graphics are very slow. *Alt + Tab* takes a lot of time (seconds).

- After reading some threads, I also removed Cinnamon desktop, but it didn't change anything.
- Tried running in FailSafeX mode, but still the performance is poor.

I had to ultimately fall back to Gnome Flashback (no effects). Gnome flashback works fine without any issues.

Can anyone please help me get back to Unity, else I will have a very hard time running using Gnome.

#### UPDATE

Here is my [/var/log/dmesg](http://pastebin.com/vmEMfMNE) and [/var/log/Xorg.0.log](http://pastebin.com/d4FBCa4W)

Answer (score 1):

I would start by looking at the dmesg and xorg.0.log logs (in /var/log/).  I found that the new video drivers required a BIOS upgrade.  The logs should give you a clue where to begin.  Add them to you question for a better answer.

Comment: btw I hope you know that I am not on UEFI. I am on Grub2.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/opengl/texture-filter 0
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/dash-blur-experimental 0
```

Or through GUI, `ccsm`:

- OpenGL → Change  Texture Filter from `Good` to `Fast`
- Ubuntu Unity plugin → General → Dash Blur from `Active Blur` to `No Blur`